# Getting a "setVersion" is not a function error when using indexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I tried to use following code to test the performance of IndexedDB.
The code is modified from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/ ,
It works well in chrome, but fails in Firefox 10, saying "db.setVersion is not a function".
I want to know how can I modify the code to make it work in firefox?

```
        var count=0;
        var MAX=10;
        var times=3;
        var allTime;
        var stime;
        var etime;

        var html5rocks = {};
        var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB ||
                        window.mozIndexedDB;

        if ('webkitIndexedDB' in window) {
            window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
            window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
        }

        html5rocks.indexedDB = {};
        html5rocks.indexedDB.db = null;

        html5rocks.indexedDB.onerror = function(e) {
            //console.log(e);
            alert("Why didn't you allow my web app to use IndexedDB?!");  
        };

        html5rocks.indexedDB.open = function(type) {

        var request = indexedDB.open("todos");
            request.onsuccess = function(e) {
            var v = "1.20";
            html5rocks.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
            var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
            // We can only create Object stores in a setVersion transaction;
            if (v!= db.version) {

                var setVrequest = db.setVersion(v);
                // onsuccess is the only place we can create Object Stores
                setVrequest.onerror = html5rocks.indexedDB.onerror;
                setVrequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
                    if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("todo")) {
                        db.deleteObjectStore("todo");
                    }

                    var store = db.createObjectStore("todo",
                        {keyPath: "number"});
                        addTest();
                };

            }
            else addTest();
            };

            request.onerror = html5rocks.indexedDB.onerror;

        }

        html5rocks.indexedDB.addTodo = function(todoText,num) {
            var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
            var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
            var store = trans.objectStore("todo");

            var data = {
            "text": todoText,
            "number": num
            };

            var request = store.put(data);

            request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                count++;
                if(count>=times*MAX)
                {
                    etime=new Date;
                    var t=document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=t+((etime.valueOf()-stime.valueOf())/times)+"<br/>";
                    allTime=0;stime=new Date;count=0;
                    getTest();
                }

            };

            request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error Adding: ", e);
            };
        };

        html5rocks.indexedDB.getTodo = function(id) {
            var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
            var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
            var store = trans.objectStore("todo");

            var request = store.get(id);

            request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                count++;
                if(count>=times*MAX)
                {
                    etime=new Date;
                    var t=document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=t+((etime.valueOf()-stime.valueOf())/times)+"<br/>";
                    allTime=0;stime=new Date;count=0;
                    delTest();
                }
            };

            request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error getting: ", e);
            };
        };

        html5rocks.indexedDB.deleteTodo = function(id) {
            var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
            var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
            var store = trans.objectStore("todo");

            var request = store.delete(id);

            request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                count++;
                if(count>=times*MAX)
                {
                    etime=new Date;
                    var t=document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=t+((etime.valueOf()-stime.valueOf())/times)+"<br/>";
                    allTime=0;stime=new Date;count=0;
                    dataTest();
                }
            };

            request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error Adding: ", e);
            };
        };

        html5rocks.indexedDB.addData = function(d) {
            var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
            var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
            var store = trans.objectStore("todo");
            var data={
                "text":d,
                "number":1
            };
            var request = store.put(data);

            request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                etime=new Date;
                var t=document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=t+((etime.valueOf()-stime.valueOf()))+"<br/>";
            };

            request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error Adding: ", e);
            };
        };



        function addTest() {
            for(i=1;i<=times*MAX;i++)
                html5rocks.indexedDB.addTodo('          ',i);
        }
        function getTest() {
            for(i=1;i<=times*MAX;i++)
                html5rocks.indexedDB.getTodo(Math.round(Math.random()*(MAX*times-1)+1));
        }
        function delTest() {
            for(i=1;i<=times*MAX;i++)
                html5rocks.indexedDB.deleteTodo(i);
        }
        function dataTest() {
            data=' ';
            for(i=1;i<=21;i++)
                data=data+data;
            stime=new Date
            html5rocks.indexedDB.addData(data);
        }
        function init() {
            stime=new Date;
            allTime=0;
            html5rocks.indexedDB.open();

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec is not finalized.  This is currently shipped as the property **mozIndexedDB** in Gecko and **webkitIndexedDB** in Chrome until the standard is finalized. So you have to write for moz also. Now this code is only for webkit.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB

Comment: Thanks. And does chrome support this "onupgradeneeded" event? In other words do I need to keep the "setVersion" for chrome to use?

Comment: On 17+ chrome has plan to implement it but its not confirmed yet. Its good to use setVersion for now & chrome will support it for few more releases, even if it implements "onupgradeneeded".

Answer (score 1):

[setVersion() is Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IDBDatabase#setVersion%28%29_.0A.0ADeprecated)

> The new way is to define the version in the [IDBDatabase.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IDBFactory#Browser_compatibility) method

firefox from version 10.0 implements open() with the new specification in which an indexeddb database `IDBDatabase` version is set as the second parameter of the `open()` method

**example**

```
var v = "1.20";
var request = indexedDB.open("todos", v);
```

[html5](/questions/tagged/html5) [indexeddb](/questions/tagged/indexeddb) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the one chosen as the correct answer.

The problem is that the IndexedDB examples on HTML5Rocks were written to the pre-January IndexeDB spec. The working group has since published a breaking change going from the `setVersion` API to the new `onupgradedneeded` style.

Here, Firefox is technically correct to fail. [Star this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108223) if you want to see Chrome do the same.